# Web View Zooming Control

Tags: android, android-webview

```
htmlp = URLEncoder.encode(desc,"utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," ");
            WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            wv.setInitialScale(70);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
            wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wv.loadData(htmlp,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

In htmlp contains HTML content(tags). Now I have to enable zooming control, but using above code it is not working. Is anything I have to enable in xml part of the webview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Zoom should work just with `wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`. Have you tried with that setting only?

Comment: yes....but no result....so i have added those methods. But still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works good in my case.Try it for your case..
**In manifest file..**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
```

**webview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>
  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

In activity..

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = this.myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    this.myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

change to false

Answer (score 0):

At last I have solved this problem. The problem was in the design section. Just changed the layout param to this:

```
WebView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
```