# Enable zoom in WebView android

Tags: java, android, webview

I can not enable the zoom clamp on WebView in Android

I am new to programming, already tried everything and can not solve the problem.

Being new here , I can not attach image.

WebViewActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://200.99.150.163/sacsptrans/hrecinicial.aspx");


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
                        // prevent open in external browser
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                return false;
            }   

        });

    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to enable zoom on the webView, add the following code in **onTuchEvent override method**:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

If your `webview` goes to another url and you want to mantain the zoom level
use the [webSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

If you want a pre-defined zoom when `webview` loads use:

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);  // int value 50 = 50% -- 200 = 200%
```

It works pretty well for all device resolutions.

**UPDATE:** If any of those are working (weeeird...) try this:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
    getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    final View zoom = this.myWebView.getZoomControls();
    mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
    zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    this.myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
  }
}
```

From [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563837/web-view-zooming-control)

Comment: which api are you using? I should work in any after API 7... check my edit anyway ;)

Comment: It did not work , the error in the execution , I can send emu project by email to vioce take a anlaisada calmly , please?

Comment: did you tried with `activity + framelayout` and/or  **overriding  onTuchEvent** method ??? Sorry but is easter, hard to test an android project till next week...

Comment: I that I apologize for being giving so much work , but do not have enough technical knowledge to solve this, do not know to answer this question.
I'm not in a hurry , if you can see it calmly for me , thank you !

Comment: [search here more solutions](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20webview%20zoom%20not%20working)

Answer (score 3):

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

If you need more advance `webView` you can use [webview sample](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView).

Comment: I had already done it and did not work, have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);

mWebView.setInitialScale(400); // zoom x4 (400%)
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```